# How to add specific Unity package to Git version?

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, gitignore

I want to create a custom Unity package, but since I want to work on it I want to check in a whole Unity project instead of just pushing the required package files.

So normally all packages are exluced via

```
[Pp]ackages/
```

I tried this

[.gitignore exclude folder but include specific subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533050/gitignore-exclude-folder-but-include-specific-subfolder)

```
![Pp]ackages/
[Pp]ackages/**
![Pp]ackages/BroadcastCore/
```

and this almost seems to work. Unfortunately it tries to include the `manifest.json` and `packages-lock.json` in the `Packages` directory. How can I just include all the files from the `BroadcastCore` directory?

This is a screenshot when changing the lines from

```
# The packages folder can be ignored because of Package Restore
**/[Pp]ackages/*
# except build/, which is used as an MSBuild target.
!**/[Pp]ackages/build/
```

to

```
[Pp]ackages/
```

in the .gitignore

[image]

Now I updated the single line with the three lines. Here you can see that it tries to include the files from the `Packages` directory but I think those files shouldn't exist in the remote repository

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If it tries to include files in a folder which is supposed to be ignored, that means those files are probably already tracked.

Check this with:

```
git check-ignore -v -- Packages/manifest.json
```

If it returns nothing, it is not ignored in the first place.

Try the same command after:

```
git rm --cached -- Packages/manifest.json
```

See if removing the tracked file from Git index is enough.

Comment: tested with `[Pp]ackages/` only: The second command results in a not found error. The first one returns this `.gitignore:485:[Pp]ackages/     Packages/manifest.json`

Comment: tested with my new 3 lines: The second command results in a not found error. The first one returns this `.gitignore:482:[Pp]ackages/**   Packages/manifest.json`

Comment: So it seems this file gets ignored but unfortunately it still tries to add it to the repository

Comment: @Question3r "Unfortunately it tries to include the manifest.json and packages-lock.json in the Packages directory. ": can you share in your question a screenshot of "it" trying to include those files?

Comment: @Question3r Can you double-check with a `git status`, in command line, at the root folder of your repository? Do you see `Packages/manifest.json`? And would a `git check-ignore -v -- Packages/manifest.json` still display a `.gitignore` rule then?